# Bootstrap tabs with special character ID's

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a bootstrap tab nav bar that has ID's based on the file location. Example: home.html is in sample/default/home.html. However, the tab system doesn't work when I put forward slashes and periods in the ID's. It works perfectly fine when I use different ID's such as "home", "profile", etc.

```
<div class="card" style="height:100%;">
    <div class="card-header">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs float-xs-left" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#sample/default/home.html" role="tab">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#sample/default/profile.html" role="tab">Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#sample/default/messages.html" role="tab">Messages</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#sample/default/settings.html" role="tab">Settings</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-content card-block">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="sample/default/home.html" role="tabpanel">home</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="sample/default/profile.html" role="tabpanel">profile</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="sample/default/messages.html" role="tabpanel">messages</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="sample/default/settings.html" role="tabpanel">settings</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id

Comment: Thank you for the link. I've read it, but I don't think it'll help me out with my problem. I need the ID to contain forward slashes and periods.