# Passing div names with spaces to Vue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a table in which I dynamically create IDs for divs, using Vue. The code looks like this:

```
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(group, index) in groups" >
        <td>

          <a data-toggle="collapse" :href="'#users-in-'+encodeURIComponent(group.gname)" aria-expanded="false" :aria-controls="'users-in-'+encodeURIComponent(group.gname)" v-text="group.gname"></a>

          <div class="collapse" :id="'users-in-'+encodeURIComponent(group.gname)">
            <p>some stuffs</p>
          </div>

        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Some other stuff</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

The idea is to dynamically generate `#users-in-someGroupName` div names for each group. Above example works well, but it crashes when I have spaces in group names. In console I get JQuery error:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #users-in-some%20group%20with%20space
```

I added `encodeURIComponent` in order to mitigate it, but it seems Vue/JQuery cannot handle this. How can I pass spaces in div names?

Comment: What is the jQuery code that is associated with the HTML?

Comment: There is no explicit jQuery code, the table is inside a pane, which is inside a tab. They're all built on Bootstrap though. The stack trace refers only to jQuery and Bootstrap code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41355252/bootstrap-tabs-with-special-character-ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although an [`id` in HTML 5](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp) is pretty much unrestricted in terms of characters, it looks like Bootstrap really wants them to be [HTML-4 compliant](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id).

Rather than `encodeURIComponent` (which replaces special characters with other special characters), write a function to [Replace special characters in a string with _ (underscore)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705194/replace-special-characters-in-a-string-with-underscore)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried to avoid that (because it will affect my backend and DB a bit), but it seems to be the only way here. I missed this in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also take help of computed property to convert space to underscore.

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello'
  },
  computed: {
    // a computed getter
    underScoreName: function (name) {
      return name.split(' ').join('_')
    }
  }
})
```

You can use this underScoreName computed property to change space into underscore.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(group, index) in groups" >
        <td>

          <a data-toggle="collapse" :href="'#users-in-'+underScoreName(group.gname)" aria-expanded="false" :aria-controls="'users-in-'+underScoreName(group.gname)" v-text="group.gname"></a>

          <div class="collapse" :id="'users-in-'+underScoreName(group.gname)">
            <p>some stuffs</p>
          </div>

        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Some other stuff</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```